# Is there a mistake in these two equations describing force between magnetic dipoles?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-moment, dipole, dipole-moment

The first equation appears [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Magnetic_dipole-dipole_interaction). (*Force between magnets#Magnetic dipole-dipole interaction* on Wikipedia)

$$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{m_1}, \mathbf{m_2}) = \frac{3\mu_0}{4\pi r^5} \left[(\mathbf{m_1} \cdot \mathbf{r})\mathbf{m_2} + (\mathbf{m_2}\cdot \mathbf{r})\mathbf{m_1} + (\mathbf{m_1}\cdot \mathbf{m_2})\mathbf{r} - \frac{5(\mathbf{m_1}\cdot\mathbf{r})(\mathbf{m_2}\cdot \mathbf{r})}{r^2} \mathbf{r}\right]$$
where $\mathbf{r}$ is defined as the distance vector between the two dipoles, $\mathbf{m_{1,2}}$ are the magnetic moment vectors for the first/second dipoles and $r$ is the distance between the dipoles.

The second appears [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Forces_between_two_magnetic_dipoles). (*Magnetic moment#Forces between two magnetic dipoles* on Wikipedia)
$$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{m_1}, \mathbf{m_2}) = \frac{3\mu_0}{4\pi r^4} \Big[(\mathbf{m_1}\cdot  \hat{\mathbf{r}})\mathbf{m_2} + (\mathbf{m_2}\cdot  \hat{\mathbf{r}})\mathbf{m_1} + (\mathbf{m_1} \cdot \mathbf{m_2}) \hat{\mathbf{r}} - 5\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{m_1}\cdot  \hat{\mathbf{r}})(\mathbf{m_2}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{r}})\Big]$$
where $ \hat{\mathbf{r}}$ is the unit vector between the two dipoles, $\mathbf{m_{1,2}}$ are the magnetic moment vectors for the first/second dipoles, $r$ is the distance between the dipoles.

With the variables defined as they are, I would think that dividing each $\mathbf{r}$ in the first equation by $r$ (converting the distance vectors to unit vectors) would produce the second equation. It does not, however, but dividing each $\mathbf{r}$ in the second equation by $r$ does produce the first.

Are these variable definitions backwards, or have I done something wrong?

Comment: _"but dividing each $\mathbf{r}$ in the second equation by $r$ does produce the first"_ There are no $\mathbf{r}$s in the second equation, so what did you divide? If you use $\mathbf{r} = r \hat{\mathbf{r}}$ in the first equation, you get the second one. And if you use $\hat{\mathbf{r}} = \mathbf{r} / r$ in the second equation, you get the first one.

Comment: I made a quite naive mistake that you've now cleared up. Thank you very much!